# Why is my transistor beta lower than expected?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, current-source

I bought these transistors on digikey: [BC549CTA](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BC/BC546.pdf)

Reading through the datasheet, (and on digikey's page), I am led to believe that the DC gain for this transistor is at minimum 420 [@ 2mA, 5V]. The actual range is actually like 420 - 800 or something.

Anyway, I was trying to build a current source for a differential pair and wanted to pump out about 2mA of current through the transistor, so I set it up like this for a quick test:

[image]

I want to put the emitter at about 1V, so at 1V / 2 mA gives 500 Ohms, I went with 470 Ohms as the closest value I have. That ought to put the emitter at 940 mV.

To bias the transistor, I multiplied the emitter resistance by beta (assumed 600) and divided by 10 as a rule of thumb. This means I'll have to aim for a base resistance of about 28k and a base voltage of about 1.5-1.6

The divider above should work out to a Thevenin Equivalent of about 28.7k, pretty dang close.

After the quick sketch, I built the thing and to my surprise my design did not work out at all. The emitter voltage worked out to be 447 mV. That's way below what I expected. I expected to be at least somewhat close to a volt, but this is less than half. The base is the same way, about 1.05 V. Needless to say, I'm definitely not getting 2mA from this source.

I've built a few more circuits with different values. I tried to reduce the total base resistance to reduce the loading effect, but that made it worse. Eventually, I tried to work out the beta value backwards, and it looks like the transistor has a real beta value of about 43-44, not even close to the claimed 420-800. So, with that, the expected resistance looking into the base is about 20k. I worked out values of 18k for R1 and 2.8k for R2 (bias resistance of about 2.42k). This time, the values agree! The emitter voltage is about 940 mV, and the base voltage is about 1.54 V.

What gives guys? I thought maybe the spec for the transistor drifts a lot when it's outside of the measured conditions (5V @ 2mA Ic), but I used a 5V supply as well and the results are the same. I'm really confused.

For those old designs, the ones I initially thought should work, I duplicated the same circuit with my old 2N3904s, and the values were right on the money. I really cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The measured conditions are Vce = 5V, not Vc =5V.  You are closer to saturation than the measured conditions.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but are you sure you didn’t exchange C and E?

Comment: @ScottSeidman, You're right! I completely misread that! Yet, even with 2mA and 3.3k in the collector, that would end up being Vce = 12 - 0.002*3300 - 1V = 4.4 V. Is the 0.6 mV that big of a deal? The Vce(sat) param says quotes saturation voltages in the mV.

Comment: @user2233709, I double checked the writing on my transistor to figure out which transistor I bought. It says BC549C-F50. The datasheet link I got right off the digikey purchase order, so at least it's the part I order (although, I could have gotten different of course).

Comment: Your numbers look OK. If you've checked your building skills and circuit with an old transistor and got the expected answer, and you've bought the trannies from a reputable source, then you could have damaged one. Check with another device. The highest beta selection will be slightly more prone to ESD, but not a lot. And consider 2233709's question, I always get those dang things wrong first time.

Comment: You mean 600mV.  It might be a big enough deal.  Beta gets smaller as you approach saturation.  IIRC, people usually underspec beta by a factor of about 7 for a saturated transistor, and it has to get there somehow.  If you use your MINIMUM beta, you're only off the spec for Vce=5V, 2mA, by a factor of about 2.  Push comes to shove, Beta is just considered a bad parameter to design around.

Comment: Note that the minimum current gain (hfe) under the test conditions is 110, not 400

Comment: Try using the meter diode measurement to make sure your connections are correct. Despite you have already double checked the pin-out via datasheet, it´s never a bad idea triple checking with a meter and solve this problem out once for all.

Comment: You can distinguish C-B junction from E-B junction on most BJTs because it will have a bit lower drop when measured with a multimeter on diode range.

Comment: @KamilJarosz I meant are you sure you did not exchange the C and E pins of the transistor?

Comment: Moreover, the circuit you´re trying to build should not heavily rely on beta. That´s why you reduce the input impedance: in order to face less changes due to beta variations with temperature

Comment: @ScottSeidman, Yes, I'm sorry, I mean 0.6 V (600 mV).

Comment: @user2233709, Ahh, I see what you mean. Yes, that was the issue. I double checked against the datasheet. Such a brain fart.

Comment: @IronMaiden, Sorry mate, I misunderstood what user2233709 was saying. I thought he was asking me if I got the datasheet for the right part.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, what about that table at the bottom of that page. I thought that was the actualy hFE for the different serial number endings. Since I have part BC549C (ending in C), wouldn't that make my part have am hFE in the range of 420 - 800?

Comment: That is confusing.  It's really hard to know what they mean.  When you find datasheets that are less than crystal clear, if it's critical that you get something right, the best course of action is often to find a part with a clearer spec.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The beta value you are getting is rather typical for a transistor in reverse active mode. That is, using the collector as an emitter.

Assuming every thing else is ok (vendor, supplier, and manufacturer) then confusing the pin-out is your most likely issue.

Comment: Yes! Incredible. This is the second time I've got caught in that trap. I double checked the datasheet. I thought that form factor always had the same pinout. I need to staple "double check pinout in datasheet" to my forehead or something. Thank you sir.

Comment: @KamilJarosz -- don't fret too hard :) pinout mistakes are easy to make!

Comment: I was curious why we all had this issue at least once.  So I discovered the ancient BC3xx series were CBE instead of EBC.  There were reasons why the TO-92 standards changed.

Comment: Ah but then these British Engineers drove on the right side of the road.